# Asp.net 3.5 White Screen on App Pool Recycle on IIS 6.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-6, windows-server-2003, application-pool

## Background:

I have an old ASP.NET application written in .Net 3.5 (2.0 CLR) running on a 32-bit Windows 2003 server that has IIS-6 on it.  We recently had to change some of the data access layer portions for some changes coming in the future and went to deploy it from TFS.  We've made recent deployments for other minor adjustments and the msbuild file is exactly the same as well is the target so no changes other than some coding ones.

## Problem:

When the coding changes were code reviewed and committed I initiated a deployment which was successful.  I opened up the site on the development server to do some spot checking before handing it over to the testers to begin more thorough regression testing and everything looked great - no issues.

An hour or so later, when they went to start testing, I get a ticket that the website is just a white screen, nothing is even coming back from the web server as the source of the page.  Nothing is showing up in any logs on the server in the event viewer, nothing in IIS logs other than successful page requests, try a few other things and nothing.

So, I deploy the website again from TFS, it loads up fine and I can perform a lot of actions perfectly without seeing the white screen.  Logs look good so I think of it as a fluke and go on about my tasks.

Then the ticket comes back, its doing it again, white screen of death, and I'm completely perplexed as to why.

## Troubleshooting thus far:

1. The initial load of the website works after both automated and manual deployment.
2. Failure happens after the app pool has been recycled post a working deployment from [1].
3. Fiddler shows nothing strange happening between the server and the client.
4. Switching the website from 2.0 to 4.0 (our next upgrade) has the same effect.
5. Removing all files from the "Temporary ASP.NET Files" folder for the appropriate framework in [4] does revert it back to the state of [1] however clearing that out between app pool recycles isn't desired as that isn't needed for other applications.
6. I've tried both  tag with debug and both flags set to true and false with the same results.
7. Compared both the msbuild file and solution/project/web.config settings with other applications that have undergone this upgrade with no differences.

## Findings:

The issue seems to be the previous assembly from the last "live" application pool remains in the "Temporary ASP.NET Files" directory stays there as well as a file with the exact same name just appended with a ".delete" (i.e. assemblyname.dll.delete).  This just cycles with each application pool restart.

So, for the first run the website's dll will be in there and everything will work.  Lets say it was MyApplication_0001.dll.

On the second run MyApplication_0001.dll, MyApplication_0001.dll.delete, and MyApplication_0002.dll will be in there.

On the third run MyApplication002.dll, MyApplication002.dll.delete, and MyApplication003.dll will be in there.

So, the pattern is it keeps the last one, has an empty .delete file with the same name, and the new dll.

If I delete the extra file the site will come right back up so the runtime must see two of the same named namespaces/classes/signature and can't figure out which is the correct and choke - just with no errors anywhere logged.

Any ideas on things to check on in configuration at the application/iis/server level?

## Updates:

**2014-06-24**: Confirmed that this occurs on a Windows 7 PC as well with IIS 7.5 running .Net 2.0 on a classic application pool in 64-bit framework.

## Answers to questions:

1. The inital HTTP response is 401 for NTLM then I get a 200 that returns the white screen post authentication.
2. The white screen is returned on the server and on all developers/testers machines on various browsers and versions.

Comment: What HTTP response code is being sent when the white screen is encountered?

Comment: The white screen is only seen on the tester's computer? And can this been seen immediately after the deployment, or some time after you have "spot checked"?